# Proof of matrix representation equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

$\begin{bmatrix}
T \\
\end{bmatrix}_\mathscr{F}$ = $P^{-1}$ $\begin{bmatrix} 
T \\
\end{bmatrix}_\mathscr{E}$ $P$

Where $\mathscr{F}$ is the new basis and $\mathscr{E}$ is the old basis. $P$ represents the change-of-basis matrix, from $\mathscr{E}$ to $\mathscr{F}$. $\begin{bmatrix}
T \\
\end{bmatrix}_\mathscr{F}$ is the matrix representation of a linear transformation $T$, with respect to the basis $\mathscr{F}$. Same thing goes for $\begin{bmatrix}
T \\
\end{bmatrix}_\mathscr{E}$

Can someone prove why that equation is true? I have no idea how to show that it's true.

Comment: What part of this identity is not clear to you? Your description suggests that you have understood at least every single matrix in the equation. What do you think is left to prove? (This is not meant as bashing, I honestly want to help you, but do not see the problem yet)

Comment: @PrudiiArca I understand the identity. I just don't understand how we got there. Why is it true? Where did we get the equality from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning** the $\cong$ symbol is symmetric, yet when writing $\varphi: K^n \cong V$ I explicitly mean that it is an isomorphism going from $K^n$ to V.

A choice of basis of an $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space is nothing else than a choice of isomorphism $\varphi:K^n \cong V$ (the standard basis of $K^n$ determines your basis of $V$). A linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ becomes a linear transformation $T_\varphi = \varphi^{-1}T\varphi:K^n \rightarrow K^n$, which in turn bijectively corresponds to a matrix $[T]_\varphi\in K^{n\times n}$.

Now, given another basis/isomorphism $\psi:K^n \cong V$ we get another linear transformation $T_\psi=\psi^{-1}T\psi:K^n \rightarrow K^n$ with corresponding matrix representation $[T]_\psi$. Now note that we get a commuting diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
K^n &\overset{\varphi}{\cong} &V& \overset{\psi}{\cong} & K^n\\
\downarrow T_\varphi &&\downarrow T && \downarrow T_\psi\\
K^n &\overset{\varphi}{\cong} &V& \overset{\psi}{\cong} & K^n
\end{array}$$

Finally note that the composite $\psi^{-1}\varphi:K^n \cong K^n$ is corresponds precisely to the matrix $P$ changing from the basis $\varphi$ to the basis $\psi$. The commutativity of the diagram thus corresponds to the matrix identity $P^{-1}[T]_\psi P = [T]_\varphi$...